# SQL Server: Get TotalCount Per Hour Per Table

Tags: sql-server, database

Is there a query where you can get the total data count that has been added to a table within the last 24 hours? For example, table A acquired 25000 data within the last 24 hours. Previously, there were 1 million of data. Now, including the last 24 hours, it has now 1 million and 250 thousand of data.

I can only acquire all total count of data of all tables in my database using this query below:

```
SELECT t.name as TableName, i.rows as TotalCount
FROM sys.tables as t 
    JOIN sys.sysindexes as i 
ON t.object_id = i.id 
WHERE indid IN (0,1) 
ORDER BY i.rows DESC, t.name
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no way natively to do that, but it would be simple enough to build that using an audit table and trigger. Here's an example [link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4055/create-a-simple-sql-server-trigger-to-build-an-audit-trail/), but it wouldn't have to capture anything other than insert.

Comment: Sadly, we can't alter the database any longer. What we can do is only Select statement. Thanks, though. Appreciate it.

Comment: schedule your query to execute every hour and log the result into a table

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if there is any inbuilt SQL feature or query. You can achieve this by adding a date time column.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is schedule a python, shell or any other script which would execute the query and log the output at regular intervals(You can decide upon the intervals as required). Then later, refer the logs to find the difference.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that info unless you implement a log/tracking mechanism. You have the following options to implement:

- Add a datetime column that will be the insertion date (default `GETDATE()`). Use this column to count the rows between a particular date range.
- Add an after insert trigger to the table that either inserts a row with current datetime into a log table, or increments a daily or periodic counter.
- Schedule a process that counts total records and compares to previous counts to calculate the difference (or just log the total amount).
- Use CDC (Change Data Capture) module of newer SQL Server versions.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but you can query the transaction log using `sys.fn_dblog`. NOTE: This is based on the limitations you've described...it would be much better to use an audit table and trigger.

Depending on when the transaction_log is truncated, you do can possibly do what you are trying to do with something like the following:

```
SELECT
 [Current LSN],
 [Transaction ID],
 [Operation],
  [Transaction Name],
 [CONTEXT],
 [AllocUnitName],
 [Page ID],
 [Slot ID],
 [Begin Time],
 [End Time],
 [Number of Locks],
 [Lock Information]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL)
WHERE Operation IN 
   ('LOP_INSERT_ROWS','LOP_BEGIN_XACT','LOP_COMMIT_XACT')
```

Each insert transaction will have an associated row for operation 'LOP_BEGIN_XACT' and 'LOP_COMMIT_XACT', and will have one or more rows for operation 'LOP_INSERT_ROWS'. If you join the associated rows on [Transaction ID], then you can filter start date on [Begin Time].

**Keep in mind, once the log is truncated all bets are off so this may not be helpful to you at all.**

A little background on transaction logs: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).